# Does it matter if factory-split bushings don't "close up" when installed?

Tags: suspension, bushing

I just replaced my front stabilizer bar bushings to fix a clunking noise I was getting. It solved the problem and the clunking is gone, but the replacement bushings don't seem to fit quite exactly. They are the correct aftermarket units.

**driver/left side bushing**
[image: driver/left side bushing]

**passenger/right side bushing**
[image: passenger/right side bushing]

The bar is centered as far as I can tell, the bushings are fully in the grooves, brackets are torqued to spec (29 ft/lb) and oriented correctly.

I've tried removing and reseating the bushings, shuffling the bar and brackets around a bit, but I just can't get these bushings to close up.

Is this a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Not all aftermarket parts are created equal, so they are not always an exact fit. Lubricate the moving surfaces (bushing-to-bar) with silicone grease and most likely this setup will last very reasonable length of time.

Comment: So, worst case scenario, the $10 bushings just might wear out sooner than otherwise?

Comment: Yes, and lubricating it is the important part there vs. whether the bushing actually "closes".